# How I can use external JavaScript library imported as ES6 module in Angularjs service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service that require external library, for example `moment`. I import that library as ES6 module. But because AngularJS service defined using closure approach, library is not available when `funcA()` is being been called.

#### service.js

```
import moment from 'moment';
export function DataService() {
    return { 

        funcA: function() {
            return moment().startOf('day').fromNow(); 
        } 
    };
}
```

#### controller.js

```
MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'DataService', ...];
export function MyCtrl($scope, $state, DataService, ...) {

    function setInitialDate () {
      ctrl.someDate = DataService.funcA();
    }
}
```

#### app.js

```
import {DataService} from './service.js';
import {MyCtrl} from './controller.js';

var services = angular.module('services', []); 
services.factory('DataService', DataService);

angular.module('mycontrollers').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

I can import external library into window object, and get access to it inside service using `$window`. Is there exists other way to get access to library, that was imported as ES6 module, from inside AngularJS service?

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: What you have looks like it should work. You may need to add more details to your question

Comment: @NagaSaiA moment is undefined inside `funcA()`. It is not a message in console, it is the state of `moment ` variable when function is being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the factory and the controller in the same module:

```
import {DataService} from './service.js';
import {MyCtrl} from './controller.js';

angular.module('app',[])
.factory('DataService', DataService);
.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

Comment: It works, but during tests I should mock `app` module. It may be inconvenient if I need to tests only services. Can you suggest the other approach so I could keep modules separated?